# R - Long multi-use functions or short functions?

Tags: r, function

I am building an R package that contains a framework of functions that all support a certain type of project. I was wondering if its better design to have robust functions that can do different types of similar operations, or have a separate function for each different thing.

For example (purely made up), lets say I had a function that builds a certain type of table. There are two different ways that I can build the table, "way 1" and "way 2". The final output of either way is going to be the same type of table, how the table is made is very different. More different than just changing one argument or so that varies based on the 'way'.

For this example, should I build one larger function that takes an argument `,build_way = 'way 1'` or should I build two different functions for each way?

Comment: I'd say that you should build one function for each way, then build another one that takes an argument of which way to use and apply to one of them. That helps avoid really long functions, and it's better for debug purpose.

Comment: It scales nicely too. Want to add a new way? Build a new function, add it to your wrapper. No need to edit and risk breaking the existing ways.

Comment: And, if you find yourself copy/pasting code from one way to another, break that out into a separate utility function so your code isn't repeated.

Comment: Thanks for the input both, thats where I was leaning, but just wanted to get some extra insight